# Append filename to URL via link_to method- Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, prawn

I need to add a filename to the url via the link_to method.

My current URL looks like

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/vouchers/17/voucher_orders
```

I'm using the prawn gem in my application to generate a PDF however to get the PDF with prawn I need to append the filename to the end of the URL like this.

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/vouchers/17/voucher_orders/17.pdf
```

My link_to method looks like this.

```
<%= link_to "Printable Voucher (PDF)", voucher_voucher_orders_path(@voucher, format: "pdf") %>
```

which gives me the following URL.

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/vouchers/17/voucher_orders.pdf
```

How can I append the "/voucher id" to the end of the URL in the link_to method?

Comment: I would check if prawn has an appropriate helper method and if not, create your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use a + sign to add that to the link.  It would look like this

```
<%= link_to "Printable Voucher (PDF)", voucher_orders_path(@voucher)+'voucher_orders'+@voucher.id+'.pdf' %>
```

Play around with that.  It's ugly but you can probably make it work.

Comment: Personally I would make a helper out of that concatenation though, like voucher_orders_pdf_path or something. That way you can add a test for it, and keep the erb clean.

Comment: Thanks guys. I can make this work. I'll look at making a helper. I just needed to convert the voucher id to a string.

voucher_voucher_orders_path(@voucher)+'/'+@voucher.id.to_s+'.pdf